# How to skip delete confirmation page in Django admin for specific model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a huge amount of data, and Django creates delete confirmation page a very long time. I have to skip this process and delete data without any confirmation. I have tried some solutions from the internet, but it doesn't work - I still see confirmation page.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You can create your own action instead of using admin's default `delete selected stuff` [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages) is the doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.delete()

class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = (delete_selected,)
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations on the code for OP?

Comment: I can confirm this works! Should really be the accepted answer.

Comment: What if I just want to override the queryset for not to show related objects,  but YES delete those objects??

Answer (score 5):

Django 2.1 [released](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.1/#minor-features) the new ModelAdmin method [get_deleted_objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_deleted_objects) that allows to specify parameters to the confirmation screen for both single and multiple delete (e.g. using the delete action).

In my case, I wanted to delete a list of objects with several relationships, but set with cascade deletion. I ended up with something like this:

```py
def get_deleted_objects(self, objs, request):                                                                                                                                
      deleted_objects = [str(obj) for obj in objs]
      model_count = {MyModel._meta.verbose_name_plural: len(deleted_objects)}
      perms_needed = []
      protected = []
      return (deleted_objects, model_count, perms_needed, protected)
```

I could include other models in the model_count dict, getting only the count, for example, to still avoid list thousands of minor instances that I don't need to see individually.