# How to override intermediate delete confirmation queryset in admin, I need not show related objects

Tags: python, django, django-views, admin

I have a master model with 1 to 10,000 related objects, when I choose to delete one of them, confirmation delete view takes too long to show and I really do not need to show them in that confirmation in admin.

How can I overrides intermediate confirmation queryset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip delete confirmation page in Django admin for specify model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365331/how-to-skip-delete-confirmation-page-in-django-admin-for-specify-model)

Comment: That is for skip, I want to confirm.
What if I just want to override the queryset for not to show related objects,  but YES delete those objects??

Comment: In that case just override the template - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html